# Certain selector syntax not working in Symfony2's CssSelector component (within DomCrawler)

Tags: php, dom, symfony, css-selectors, symfony-components

I have a question about the dom crawler, or more specifically, the CssSelector Component. When I run

```
$descendants = $crawler->filter('ul > li');
```

on a multi dimensional list, I get all direct children. But when I run

```
$descendants = $crawler->filter('ul li');
```

I expect to get all descendants, but instead I get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It think you can't get the descendants with the CssSelector component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouter J was right, it's not possible. But this is an acceptable workaround:

```
$descendants = $crawler->filter('ul')->filter('li');
```